# Error message triggered by Server side validation not displayed under the correct tab

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have got tabs and for each tab I have got server side validation. If an error comes up in "Tab 2" the error is displayed but "Tab 1" is shown therefore the user doesn't see the error message.See screencast here https://www.screencast.com/t/NRU5L44F and see the issue can be reproduced  here https://www.corobori.com/TestPage2018.aspx

```
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home"><h4 class="azul">Tab 1 </h4></a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1"><h4 class="azul">Tab 2</h4></a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2"><h4 class="azul">Tab 3</h4></a></li>

    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div class="contact-form">
        Tab 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <p class="padding-20">
        Tab 2
        </p>
        <div class="contact-form">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNoRegCorreo" cssclass="contact-input" runat="server" placeholder="Some data" ></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CustomValidator id="valCorreo" ForeColor="Red"   runat="server" ErrorMessage="This is an error message  " Display="Dynamic"
        ValidationGroup="grpNoREG" ControlToValidate="txtNoRegCorreo" ValidateEmptyText="True" ></asp:CustomValidator>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <asp:Button ValidationGroup="grpNoREG" ID="btnNoREG" runat="server" cssclass="contact-button" Text="Click to test" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
        <p class="padding-20">
        Tab 3
        </p> 
    </div>

    </div>
```

The validation just returns false

```
    Private Sub valCorreo_ServerValidate(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles valCorreo.ServerValidate
    args.IsValid = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer on [asp.net forum](https://forums.asp.net/t/2136602.aspx?Error%20message%20triggered%20by%20Server%20side%20validation%20not%20displayed%20under%20the%20correct%20tab) gave me a clue here is a working solution

```
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="<%=homeTabClass1()%>" ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home"><h4 class="azul">Tab 1 </h4></a></li>
    <li class="<%=homeTabClass2()%>"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1"><h4 class="azul">Tab 2</h4></a></li>
    <li class="<%=homeTabClass3()%>"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2"><h4 class="azul">Tab 3</h4></a></li>

    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in <%=homeTabClass11()%>">
        <div class="contact-form">
        Tab 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade <%=homeTabClass21()%>">
        <p class="padding-20">
        Tab 2
        </p>
        <div class="contact-form">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNoRegCorreo" cssclass="contact-input" runat="server" placeholder="Some data" ></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CustomValidator id="valCorreo" ForeColor="Red"   runat="server" ErrorMessage="This is an error message  " Display="Dynamic"
        ValidationGroup="grpNoREG" ControlToValidate="txtNoRegCorreo" ValidateEmptyText="True" ></asp:CustomValidator>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <asp:Button ValidationGroup="grpNoREG" ID="btnNoREG" runat="server" cssclass="contact-button" Text="Click to test" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade <%=homeTabClass31()%>">
        <p class="padding-20">
        Tab 3
        </p> 
    </div>

    </div>
```

And the code behind is:

```
Public Class TestPage2018
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim sClass1 As String
Dim sClass2 As String
Dim sClass3 As String
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    sClass1 = "active"
    sClass2 = ""
    sClass3 = ""
End Sub


Private Sub btnNoREG_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNoREG.Click
    If Me.IsValid = True Then

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub valCorreo_ServerValidate(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles valCorreo.ServerValidate
    sClass1 = ""
    sClass2 = "active"
    sClass3 = ""
    args.IsValid = False
End Sub
Public Function homeTabClass1()
    Return sClass1
End Function
Public Function homeTabClass2()
    Return sClass2
End Function
Public Function homeTabClass3()
    Return sClass3
End Function
Public Function homeTabClass11()
    Return sClass1 & " in "
End Function
Public Function homeTabClass21()
    Return sClass2 & " in "
End Function
Public Function homeTabClass31()
    Return sClass3 & " in "
End Function
```

End Class